# Помощь в вёрстке формы поиска

Tags: html, css

[image]

У меня не получается кнопка поиска: я не знаю как прописать, чтобы эта лупа была прям в поисковой строке.

Вот что уже сделал

```
<div id="put">
    <form>
       <p><input type="search" name="q" placeholder="Поиск по сайту..."> 
       <input type="submit" value="Найти"></p>
    </form>
</div><!-- end put -->
```

Comment: а какой код вы хоть уже написали ? или спрошу так а как вы думаете он должен быть ? хоть наброски.

Comment: Что именно не получается? Никто не будет за вас все делать. Показывайте что уже делали. Здесь всего лишь инпут и две кнопочки inline блоками

Comment: Во-первых, всё это выглядит слишком простым для того, чтобы возникали какие-то проблемы в реализации (кроме разве что кнопки поиска). Во-вторых, вопрос слишком общий, если у вас что-то из нарисованного не получается сверстать — что и почему?

Comment: @andreymal У меня не получается кнопка поиска , в том плане что я не знаю как прописать, что бы эта лупа была прям в поисковой строке.

Comment: Перенёс комментарий в текст вопроса

Answer (score 1):

Есть ещё вариант с использованием `position: absolute`. Суть такова: заводим контейнер под форму поиска с `position: relative`, поле поиска растягиваем на всю ширину, а кнопку размещаем поверх поля по координатам относительно правого верхнего угла.

(В примере я ещё сбрасываю родные стили `input` и `button`, не буду это расписывать, вопрос не про это)

```css
.search-form {
  display: inline-block;
  /* Это включает позиционирование относительно <form>, */
  /* а не относительно всей страницы */
  position: relative;
}

.search-form-input {
  width: 188px;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 28px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 38px 0 10px;
  border: 2px solid #d5d5d5;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.search-form-btn {
  /* Позиционирование относительно <form> */
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px; /* 2px - размер border'а поля формы */
  top: 2px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;

  /* Просто тюнинг внешнего вида */
  color: #666;
  font-weight: bold;      
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" class="search-form">
  <input type="search" class="search-form-input" placeholder="Search.." />
  <button type="submit" class="search-form-btn">
    <!-- Сюда можно запихнуть любую картинку на свой вкус -->
    O
  </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вместо значка поиска вставил букву О для простоты выполнения. Соответственно, если нужен значок, то вместе второго `input` ставится `button`, внутри которого изображение значка поиска.

```css
.search-field {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-right: none;
  outline : none; 
}
.search-button {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-left: none;
  outline : none; 
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input class="search-field" type="search" name="q" placeholder="Поиск по сайту..."> 
  <input class="search-button" type="submit" value="O">
</form>
```

Comment: минусовой маржин проставь еще что бы склеит их

Comment: @dmitriyzubkov так они и так склеены

Comment: Зачем здесь button вообще? На который еще придется событие вешать. На инпут просто бэкграунд повесить и все.

Comment: @DaemonHK скорее всего автор будет стандартный Fontawesome использовать с тегом `<i>`